# Invalid type conversion while using ANSI c

Tags: misra, ansi-c

I am facing this problem as when I am trying to build the code using ANSI C, as I was practicing writing in it and dealing with its rules, it tells me `invalid type conversion` and I don't know what to do.
this is the code line that makes the error, it is a pointer to function:

```
((CanIf_FuncTypeCanSpecial)(entry->CanIfUserRxIndication))(
    entry->CanIfCanRxPduHrhRef->CanIfCanControllerHrhIdRef,
    entry->CanIfCanRxPduId,
    CanSduPtr,
    CanDlc,
    CanId);
```

and this is how`entry->CanIfUserRxIndication` is declared, as `void *CanIfUserRxIndication;`
and this is how `CanIf_FuncTypeCanSpecial` is declared, as

```
typedef void (*CanIf_FuncTypeCanSpecial)
                 (uint8 channel, PduIdType pduId, const uint8 *sduPtr, uint8 dlc, Can_IdType canId);
```

every parameter in the conversion type is the same type as the input parameters except the first one `entry->CanIfCanRxPduHrhRef->CanIfCanControllerHrhIdRef` it is from type `enum` not `uint8`.

You can find the code on [GitHub](https://github.com/parai/OpenSAR/blob/master/communication/CanIf/CanIf.c).

and also the MISRA Rule is telling me this:

```
#1398-D (MISRA-C:2004 11.1/R) Conversions shall not be performed between a pointer to a function and any type other than an integral type
```

I tried to convert from `enum` to `uint8` to make all of the parameters as what the type conversion `CanIf_FuncTypeCanSpecial` takes, but nothing happened.

Comment: What do you mean by 'nothing happened' after you convert enum from uint8

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to cast an existing function to match a function pointer declaration that has a differing argument type.  You can cast the parameters and call such a function, but because function pointers themselves may be used anywhere in the program, at the places where they would be used the code would not know what to cast (which may result in a size difference) this is illegal.

Comment: Because this pointer to function does expect any return I removed the cast, it removed the invalid conversion type error but kept this one `expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type`, Is what I did right? or should I do something else?